# How to test login to google account using CEF + OAuth2?

Tags: authentication, oauth, chromium-embedded, google-account, cefglue

I have already asked this question on CEF Forum https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=18006. But unfortunately still haven't received an answer to my question.

According to the https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/guidance-for-our-effort-to-block-less-secure-browser-and-apps.html Google will apply OAuth2 for sing-in since January 4, 2021.
I have tried to test my CEF app for compatibility with OAuth2 according to "Test for compatibility" section from here https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/guidance-for-our-effort-to-block-less-secure-browser-and-apps.html.
When I navigated to https://accounts.google.com/ I simply added Google-Accounts-Check-OAuth-Login:true header to CefRequest in CefResourceRequestHandler.OnBeforeResourceLoad (like described in "Test for compatibility") but nothing has changed, I still could login successfully to google account via CEF browser. After that I opened CEF browser's DevTools via Remote debugging port to check via Network tab the headers of http requests. But the result was that Google-Accounts-Check-OAuth-Login:true header has been added successfully to http requests.
So how should I simulate the case that CEF app is considered to be insecure because CEF app is not using OAuth2, when logging in to https://accounts.google.com/?

Thank you in advance